# Android sqlite dynamic insert query

Tags: android, sqlite

How to insert query in the DBAdapter? This is my sql insert query. Its create fields & values at runtime. Then need to execute.

This is my code:

```
  public void insertTableRecord(String strTableName, String strToFields, String strValues){
     String Sql = "Insert into " + strTableName + "(" + strToFields + ") Values (" + strValues + " )";
     DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(DownlaodTableActivity.this);
     dbAdapter.openDataBase();

     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    //initialValues.put("how to give", ??how to give);
    long n = dbAdapter.insertRecordsInDB(strTableName, null, initialValues);
}
```

Please tell me how to do this part.

Please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `initialValues.put(strToFields,strValue);`