# Android create Insert statement at runtime

Tags: android

I have fileds list & values list.I want to insert records using DBAdapter.I tried from this link http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/database-crud-tutorial-for-android/

```
  DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(Insert.this);
  dbAdapter.openDataBase();


ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put("name", etName.getText().toString());
initialValues.put("age", etAge.getText().toString());
long n = dbAdapter.insertRecordsInDB("user", null, initialValues);
Toast.makeText(Insert.this, "new row inserted with id = " + n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Please anybody help me how to send the fields & their values at runtime.Please help me as soon as possible

Comment: What is the problem you faced.Any error or exception or not inserted ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make fields as String array & their value also make array.For example:

```
 String[] strToFields  = new String[names.length()];
 String[] strToFieldsVal  = new String[names.length()];

    for (int k = 0; k < names.length(); k++) {
        strToFields[k] = names.getString(k);
            strToFieldsVal[k]=strVal;
    }
```

calling method like 
        insertTableRecords(actualtable, strToFields, strToFieldsVal);

method should be:

```
  public void insertTableRecords(String strTableName, String[] strToFields, String[] strValues){
    DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(DownlaodTableActivity.this);
    dbAdapter.openDataBase();

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    for(int i=0 ;i<strToFields.length;i++){
        initialValues.put(strToFields[i],strValues[i]);
    }
    long n = dbAdapter.insertRecordsInDB(strTableName, null, initialValues);
    System.out.println( " -- inserted status : --- " + n);
}
```

If you need more help see this  [Android sqlite dynamic insert query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907040/android-sqlite-dynamic-insert-query)

Comment: Thank you very much.I expected this.I will try on this